# Plesk Panel 12.5.30 Missing Settings

Tags: panel, plesk, ubuntu-server

After a clean install of Plesk Panel 12.5.30 on an Ubuntu server 14 LTE x64 my admin user has only few options in config menu

[image: few options]

i can't edit the aspect, security options, language, dns setting ecc...

i tried with centos 6 wuth the same result.

this is the config settings of my other server

[image: standard options]

and this is my licence configuration data

```
Prossimo aggiornamento chiave di licenza    12/Giu/2016
Account utente (rivenditori e clienti)  Illimitato
Domini  Illimitato
Alias di dominio    Illimitato
Account di posta    Illimitato
Utenti web  Illimitato
Language pack   1
Lingue disponibili  Qualsiasi linguaggio
Collegamenti per acquistare certificati SSL e servizi di registrazione di domini    On
Valido per i seguenti ambienti:     Virtuozzo containers, VMWare, Microsoft Hyper-V, Xen, KVM, Server Virtuozzo, LXC, Docker
Supporto di server database PostgreSQL  Off
Applicazioni Java   Off
Report sull'utilizzo del traffico   On
Gestione di notifiche   On
Gestore di eventi   On
Registro di azioni realizzate dagli utenti di Plesk.    On
Funzioni di backup e ripristino     On
Gestione di sottodomini     On
Supporto di Adobe ColdFusion    Off
Siti pubblicati con Presence Builder    0
Migration & Transfer Manager    On
Hosting del database remoto     On
Gestione della coda di posta    On
Account utente (rivenditori e clienti) in Customer and Business Manager     0
Gestione Sottoscrizioni     On
Gestione di account     On
Gestione di Clienti     On
Gestione Rivenditori    On
Disponibilità di visualizzazione personalizzata     On
Toolkit WordPress   On
Controllo posta in uscita   On
Funzionalità principali di sicurezza (ModSecurity e Fail2Ban)   On
```

what i have to do?

Answer (score 0):

It's looks like your hosting provider switching off all other UI elements.

Comment: that isn't possible because that is a vps with root access

Comment: Do you get Plesk license from Plesk company, hoster or from reseller?

Comment: Anyway, you can contact your license provider for clarification.

Comment: i took the licence from a package (server+plesk) from a reseller (netsons)
but vps is unmanaged.. so i cannot get any assistance. and parallels told me i have to ask assistance to them. i'ts a loop

Comment: It's a diffidently question to license reseller, because set of UI settings is linked with license.